# display the result in a division of another page on success function of ajax

Tags: php, ajax

there are 4 different page. product-listing.php ,product-single-page.php , product-lis.js and action.php.
when i am searching something in product-single-page.php,product-lis.js is receiving data, through ajax the keyword of the searchred item is sending to action.php and on Success it has to show result in the division which is having Id(get_product) of  product-listing page. but it is not show its result in product-listing page. i need to show search result in the product-listing page after clicking the search button.

Code

```
product-listing.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
       <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
       <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
       <script src="test.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="col-md-12">
             <div id="get_something"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>

product-single-page.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
           <link  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
           <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
           <script src="test.js" ></script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" placeholder="I'm looking for..." class="for-control"  name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" value="">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="search_btn" name="submit">GO</button>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>


product-lis.js

$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("body").delegate("#search_btn","click",function(event)
   {
     event.preventDefault();
     var keyword = $("#name").val();
     var id = $('#name').val();
     $.ajax({
     url: "action.php",
     method: "POST",
     data : { search : 1 , id : id},
     success:function(data)
        {
         $("#get_something").html(data);
        }
     })    
   });
 })


action.php`

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['search']))
 {
   $val=$_POST['id'];
  ?>
  <h1><?php  echo $val; ?></h1>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: **parse error, unexpected ';'(;)!** there's an error in your php script

Comment: To receive better answers, you should ask good questions. Format your code properly, highlight the main problem and etc... You should check the tips for formatting the question.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have access div of another page directly
because it have define in another page so its not access in same page you access another page div thats not possible

but you can redirect to that page with your `ajax response` and set response data to particular div of different page

try this one

1)product-listing.php

```
<?php
$data=@$_REQUEST['data'];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
       <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
       <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
       <script src="test.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="col-md-12">
             <div id="get_something"><?=$data?></div>
         </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

2)product-single-page.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
           <link  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
           <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
           <script src="test.js" ></script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" placeholder="I'm looking for..." class="for-control"  name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" value="">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="search_btn" name="submit">GO</button>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../library/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
{
   $("body").delegate("#search_btn","click",function(event)
   {
     event.preventDefault();
     var id = $('#name').val();
     $.ajax({
     url: "action.php",
     method: "POST",
     data : { search : 1 , id : id},
     success:function(data)
        {
             location.href="product-listing.php?data="+data;
        }
     });    
   });
 })

</script>
```

3)action.php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['search']))
 {
   $val=$_POST['id'];
  ?>
  <h1><?php  echo $val; ?></h1>
  <?php
}
?>
```